# Youtube Iframe API not playing video second time on mobile devices

Tags: youtube-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

We' ve created web site with Youtube Iframe API . On the copmuter everything is playing OK, but we have problem with mobile devices. **The video plays just one time.** When you push the play button again it doesn't work.

We checked everything and decided that there is problem with youtube player.

**I would very grateful for any solving this problem!**

p.s. Devices are: Android, IOS (Phones and Tablets), browsers are Chrome and Safari

Comment: What's the website URL? Can you provide some relevant code for your player?

Comment: Please
http://keanodesign.com/work/graphic.html

Comment: <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yD0MWkTn7ro?rel=0&autohide=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue on Safari on iOS 8 -- videos will not replay after they play through to the end.  Right now, I have a temporary fix in place:  when you detect a state change to YT.PlayerState.ENDED (0 = ended), call seekTo(0) and then pauseVideo() on the player.

Comment: I just tried your solution, but it didn't worked. Is it still working for you?